# heavy timing jitter in a loop that just sums up data, why? only imx8 suffered?

Tags: memory, embedded, real-time

I created in C a small application that does

- allocate 2 char buffers of 5 MByte
- do a loop 1000 times
- in the loop either sum up all elements of array1 or array2 (alternating), so in an internal loop of 5 Mio additions.
- measure time (clock monotonic) of this inner loop
- check for min/max and average of the time needed for one inner loop.

To my surprise on an imx8 it jitters with factor of almost 1.6 .. 2.0, so in this 1000 loops there was one of around 4.5 ms and at least on with almost 9ms. Average is of around 4.6ms, but it's not just one or two loops need longer.

This is independent on scheduler setting, so even on scheduler FIFO. No frequency scaling is active. It doesn't depend on number of cores.

The buffers are small enough to be in RAM (512MB) and big enough not to fit into Level1/2 cache.

It is not clear to me what causes this jitter. In my old system with Zynq processor this is almost free of jitter.

Compiled with -O3. With -O0 there is not jitter, but execution very slow (50ms instead of 5ms for a loop).

I have try to figure out with trace-cmd whats going on, but I can't really read the results. I need a filtering, otherwise I lose a lot of events. But what to look for?
Are there any ideas?

Try also to isolate 1 core for this task. The results are comparable. So I don't believe in scheduler but in some problem with memory subsystem.

Comment: which i.MX8 is this, specifically? Some (most?) members of that family are heterogeneous machines, with cores of different properties and potentially memory interfaces. Also, did you compare interrupt counts before and after execution? Your CPU might simply be busy serving hardware necessities!

Comment: It is imx8mp, with SMP. The processor has no active load beside that task. Of course it has to handle terminal and other things - a Linux does always "something", but with FIFO scheduler that all should be supressed (except hardware-IRQs, right).  How can see the HW-IRQ counter - and what is served by these IRQs?

Comment: /proc/interrupts

Comment: I am wondering why SAME source-code on a arm32 Dual cortex A9 (Zynq) doesn't cause issues like that. Linux is more or less same (Yocto) - but kernel on Zynq is significant older. Could I have a problem with kernel-options? What could influence the memory performance/cache handling in such a way? Could observe same jitter also on a Phytec board, so is it a problem with the SoC?

Comment: "Yocto" does by no means mean two things are similar. It is literally a system to build a custom linux distro for different hardware with completely different use cases. I still suspect interrupt load, or memory bus contention. You said "terminal and other things": you're not running a responsive graphical user interface while you're doing bare metal benchmarks, are you, by any chance?

Comment: I can tell you from painful experience that not only are Zynq 72xx series ARMs so slow that "low jitter" isn't very helpful, it's also that their memory coherence bus, which is one of the ways to exchange data between CPU and FPGA fabric, can really wreak havoc on reliable memory access performance. So, I'm a bit surprised you're praising the Zynq here!

Comment: Right. In this case the two systems share same Yocto Release, and its just a terminal thing - no graphics. And no, just the pure small system is running. Just take into account that in my example also on the Zynq nothing else is really running. Just booting a small Linux and run that simple test code on it.

Comment: You're on a timesharing system, with interrupts and other processes running. Without access to Real Time scheduling, the ability to lock oneself in memory, CPU dedication, ... you won't get continuous CPU. Performance analysis is hard.

Comment: I would double check temperature as well. Not sure if you have a heat sink. Very many modern CPUs dynamically scale when they reach certain temperature thresholds. I also wonder if there is a chance this may be related to [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/453851) but then again it doesn't sound like your code branches sufficiently enough for that.

Comment: again, frequency is fixed.  /proc/interrupts doesn't show any specific, although I am not sure what to look at. Even if my app is not running some of the IRQ cnt go up. I would go for "perf mem record" but I do get that "memory events are not supported".

Comment: There doesn't have to be a lot of interrupts - just one that is not that well behaved e.g. does a busy-wait on a register status bit or something like that - when that interrupt occurs, your application is locked out from execution until the handler completes - by the way, software interrupts are included in this, so it might not even be hardware. I am not at all surprised by 10ms scheduling delay, this should be considered normal on a linux system. If you don't want this "jitter" - do it in the kernel and lock out interrupts, or use real-time extensions, or get a more appropriate o/s.

Comment: If I would be a newbee maybe I would accept these arguments. But hey, other systems seems to be able to perform much better. I do need do do some processing of data, and such a task takes now as example instead of 20ms any time between 20 and 40ms. That is crazy! I mean I wouldn't care about a ms but this is not acceptable. Anyone with deeper knowledge how to figure out? What can be a good filter for trace-cmd? I am not able to trace all events - that are to many. AND: It is an minimalistic embedded system and I (tried) run it on isolated CPU with max priority... It's a simple predictable loop